# Requesting administrator rights within android using dot42

Tags: android, dot42

Code so far:

```
[Activity(Label="@string/activity_sample_device_admin")]
[Receiver(Enabled = true,
    Permission = "android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN")]
[MetaData(Resource = "@xml/my_admin")]
[IntentFilter(Actions = new[] { 
                                Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
                                Android.App.Admin.DeviceAdminReceiver.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED 
                                },
            Categories = new[] { Intent.CATEGORY_HOME,
                Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT,
                Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER })]
```

This creates an android manifest

```
<application android:label="dot42SandBox(by dot42.com)" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="dot42SandBox.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:resource="@xml/my_admin" />
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="dot42SandBox.MainActivity" android:enabled="true" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:resource="@xml/my_admin" />
    </receiver>
```

I have noticed the Android SDK sample(and other samples I have found online) does not duplicate the IntentFilter and have been unable to section off the intent-filter to only been attributed to either the activity or receiver. This seems to be my main issue.

Has anyone had experience using this functionality of dot42?